# `Manifest file is invalid` when installing my chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, manifest

This is my manifest.json

```
{

  "name": "Environment Quick Switch",

  "version": "1.0",

  "description": "Quick switch around develop environments.",

  "browser_action": {

    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "popup": "action.html"

  },

  "permissions": [

    "tabs", "http://*/*", "https://*/*"

  ]

}
```

I load it's folder in develop mode is OK, but after I packaged it and try to install the .crx file, comes the `Manifest file is invalid` problem .

Is anyone knows how to deal with this?

Comment: And I found I can not install crx file I compiled from google's example? I s that means I should not use chrome at version 19.0?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally fixed this problem, it's just because my develop folder's path contains Chinese characters, moved it to a English path can solve this.

Comment: Can you file a bug, regardless? Chrome shouldn't choke on non-english characters: http://new.crbug.com/ If you post the ID here, I'll make sure it gets in front of the right people.

Comment: @MikeWest I posted the issue here.  I never did this before so I don't know if my wrote in the right format . http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=118869

Answer (score 15):

I got this error too when I updated my extension. I think it happens sometimes when your extension is propagating to various servers. I came and looked at this thread and then went back to the store and tried again and it was fine.

Comment: The same is happening in 2016 too :\

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. The zip-file was accepted in the developer dashboard, but I got an error message saying that my manifest-file was invalid when installing from the webstore.

No Chineese characters on my end, it seemed like the problem was with character encoding.

I saved the manifest.json-file as ANSI - not UTF8 - and the package was accepted by the chrome webstore.

Comment: Hi Brisssou. I've googled a bit, without finding an official answer.

My answer: ANSI seems to be your best bet.

Comment: Thx phareim. In fact, in the case I was facing, submitting the extention the next day worked. ie: don't trust the store ; try to install your extention,  while (fail) {sleep; retry} ... :/

Answer (score 1):

For anyone having issues with this

To find the error in the manifest file I did the following:

1. went into the new developer dashboard
2. clicked on the "package" section where you can upload a new package
3. clicked the **CRX File   main.crx** download link for the Published package.

The site then gives a path for the error in an error message in the top of the page.

My error was in the exclude_matches list, i had an excluded path with invalid match syntax. The index in the exclude_matches part of the error message showed which entry that had errors (**exclud_matches[1]**, 0-indexed, so second entry had an error).

Answer (score 0):

I got this error too , I think maybe your resources under a SkyDrive folder  or some team code Management soft folder . Try to copy the resources to another path, such as desktop.
package your plugin with the new path , then your may success !

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem with a version number. forgetting to prefix my pre-1.0 release with a 0 as in "0.95" allowed it to upload and pass to publish, but fail to install.

In summary: ".95" bad, "0.95" good

My mistake for forgetting to install locally (was a migration), but still should probably be caught by the uploader.